# Shaping ground plane on a 4 layer USB Midi controller PCB

Tags: noise, ground, pcb-layers, ground-plane, midi

I have asked about this before but I have to admit that I didn't read enough before asking and therefore was'nt able to ask the question properly. I hope I am now.

I'm designing a 4 layer board with 46 analog inputs (rotary and slide potentiometers) and 45 digital inputs (momentary push buttons). The board is controlled by a teensy 3.6. I'm using 8-channel multiplexers (M74HC4851, [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/m74hc4851.pdf)) since the teensy doesn't have enough inputs. The multiplexers are decoupled by a 0.1uF cap each close to their vcc pin.

I'm wondering how I should shape the ground layer. I know that the most common advise in this forum is to not shape it at all and arrange the components in a smart way instead but since my layout ist mostly determined by the hardware user interface this is not really an option in my case.

Option a)
[image: Option a)]
My first idea was to separate the analog area from the digital area completely by a weirdly shaped moat and connect the analog area to teensy's agnd pin, but I learned that it's not a good idea to let signal lines cross that moat and every single analog component is connected to the multiplexers which are probably the noisiest components on my pcb.

Option b)
[image: Option b)]
My second idea was to use several moats to force the digital return currents to not cross the analog area but then I wondered if this wouldn't create several ground loops on my board. In this case (and the following cases) I wouldn't use the agnd pin of the teensy at all.

Option c)
[image: Option c)]
I could leave only one opening in the moat, put the multiplexers close to it and guide all signal lines through this opening (on their own layers of course) but this would make routing rather complicated and lead to rather long signal lines (the board is 35 by 23 centimeters or 13.3 by 9 inches)

Option d)
[image: Option d)]
My last idea was to use one solid plane and move the multiplexers to a remote area on the board. This would have similar downsides as option c) and wouldn't control the return currents of the push buttons at all.

What's my best option? What would you do? (If moving the input components was not an option)

I'm sorry for my probably very noobish approach and thankful for your answers in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you use ONE plane. All your analog sources are ON THE PCB, right?

Encourage the digital noise to remain in the MCU, by using 100,000 ohm resistors between the MCU and the logic inputs to the analog multiplexors. Adding 100pF caps may be key, as the caps help shunt any high-freq trash to Ground, reducing the trash entering your MUX logic inputs, which would upset the MUX Ground pins etc as the Trash explores **ALL** possible return paths back to the MCU.

Further encourage the digital noise to remain in the MCU, by establishing a cascade of RCRC filters in the VDD to the MCU. I call this a "local battery", which is tasked with providing the high-speed-charge demands of the MCU. You will still have Ground Loops, but you won't care, because the currents in the Ground Loops will be very small and of very low frequency.

Thusly

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFNDRb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Notice we also use the "local battery" idea, to provide very clean VDD to the analog MUXES. Otherwise the VDD trash gets injected thru the large switch capacitances (FET gate-channel capacitances) into your signals.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Unfortunately I'm not sure if I fully understand it and I have many detail questions due to the fact that I'm such a bloody beginner. It's mostly about component placement.

1.) R1,R2 & C1: It looks like they're just the beginning of a series, how many of them would you use? Shall I place them close to the MCU before VDD enters the power plane? Or just distribute them over the PCB, connecting ground & power plane?

Comment: 2.) R3, R4, C4 & C5 so you would use two bypass caps and 2 resistors per analog MUX, close to their VDD pins?

Comment: 3.) R5, R6, C7 & C8: So one resistor and one cap per logic input? Shall I place them as close as possible to the MCU and connect several MUXes to it or is it neccesary to do once for every single MUX? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Regarding R5,R6,C7,C8 logic-filters --- place them as convenient. The current thru 100Kohm is small. so the high-frequency current being shunted into Ground plane will also be small. The already small Ground current will spread out to use multiple paths back to the MCU. Yes; you can connect several MUXes to each (filtered) RC.

Comment: Regarding R3,R4,C4, C5 MUX VDD filters --- place C5 real close to the MUXes. That 1uF value is designed to provide filtered, clean, local-battery power to **all** your MUXes from just **ONE** capacitor, if you wish. If you wish. Your MUXs draw no DC power, right? Then using only C5 at the MUX VDD should be good. Use R4 and the trace between top of C4 and top of C5 as your routing flexibility, so you DO NOT SHARE THE VIAS at the Ground end of C4 and C5. I'd keep those GND vias at least 2cm apart. Do not route any fast-edge logic signals near the trace between C4 and C5.

Comment: Why would we need to keep fast-edge logic signals **away** from that trace between C4 and C5? Because that is the "local battery" voltage, to be used by the MUXes.You have spent 2 Rs and 2Cs, to create a "local clean (very clean) battery" VDD to the MUXes. Why allow that expensively created clean-power to be corrupted, from the EFI and HFI (transient currents) flowing in a fast-edge logic signal? Notice the filtered logic signals  are **slow**, so those slow edges are safe to route near or over the clean-MUX-VDD.

Comment: Regarding R1, R2, C1 ---- dual purpose! For trash from external VDD supply, R1 and C1 implement (10 ohms and 100uF) a 1 millisecond Low Pass Filter. This has minimal effect on 60 and 120Hz, but strongly filters the higher (the "singing" energy, not the "hum" energy) harmonics of power supplies. Now, consider opposite direction: trash escaping dual caps (C2,C4) placed immediately next to MCU; these caps will resonate & have some non-attenuation frequencies. R2 is crucial in dampening (parallel dampening, not serial dampening) ringing, and as LowPassFilter for trash exiting MCU. No via sharing.

Comment: Fundamentally, R2 and R4 are used to implement 2-pole filters, and to dampen any ringing. We will not get precise corners (F3dB), but we don't need precision there. We just need low DC I*R voltage drops, and massive attenuation at high frequencies, and dampening. **NOTE** the MCU VDD RC filters are **bi-directional**.

Comment: Thanks again! If I understand you correctly you'd recommend to place all the MUXes together in a remote area as in my last graphic? What if I'd prefer to have them placed as in my first graphic to make routing more convenient? Would I use several "C5s" to create several "local clean batteries" or is it just a bad idea since they'd be placed right in the middle of the PCB and be spreaded over a large area?

Comment: With the "local battery" for the MCU, expect the Ground plane to be rather CLEAN; R2 encourages the fast-edge-trash to remain in C2,C3 and the MCU. Go for convenient routing. We've used several methods --- local battery, and logic-line-filtering --- to encourage MCU trash to remain **INSIDE** the MCU. Please drop back by, and discuss how clean (or how noisy) is your resultant hardware.

Comment: Thank you, I will! One last question: What about all the digital inputs? They're basically just momentary buttons, grounding MCU pins when pushed. (The MCU has internal pullup resistors) Shouldn't I be worried about them as well?

Comment: The digital inputs are **ALL** from the MCU, right? They will look like 5pF, from an internally-noisy-trashy 0.5volt PP high-frequency ringy-dingy interferer. Keep these digital inputs away from the analog signals (including the "local clean battery" VDD for MCU and for MUXes). If can, route the digital inputs over GND plane (this is a solid plane right? with no long slits nor cuts), and the 0.5v Electric Fields will mostly get shunted to the GND plane. E-fields, if over a plane, get **attenuated** as the inverse **CUBE** of the distance. Simply route digital inputs away from analog.

Comment: Thank you, but keeping them away from the analog signals might be a little bit hard. As you can see in my graphics above, part of them are sitting right between the analog potentiometers and moving them would make absolutely no sense in terms of user friendliness.

Comment: Oh. I forgot to mention, that they're not directly from the MCU but are connected to more analog M74HC4851 MUXes.